# Content-Security-Policy with React, Electron and Webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron, scp

i'm developing an app to show trekking routes with Electron, React and Typescript (also Webpack). But, when i try to load GoogleMaps api, i get the following error:

Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=__googleMapsCallback&key={MY_KEY}' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmVNY.png)

I tried to configure my Content-Security-Policy with webpack like this:

new CspHtmlWebpackPlugin({
'base-uri': "'self'",
'object-src': "'none'",
'script-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "https:",
"https://*.googleapis.com","https://maps.gstatic.com", "'unsafe-eval'"],
'style-src': ["'unsafe-inline'", "'self'", "'unsafe-eval'"],
})
[plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ9zi.png)

And, if i inspect the header, it looks like it's working:

[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbs3W.png)

Comment: Have you solved this? im having the same problem